# Can't see new files on media library (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload, media

I have a one weird thing on my wordpress theme. When I try to upload and add a file to my product on clicking this button (when I'm inside product edit/add new page there is custom field with a file upload). **img: http://prnt.sc/pdains**

Then I got opened this box, which allow me to upload a new file. **img: https://prnt.sc/pdalrd**
Also I can click on tabs here and see already uploaded files in media library. **img: https://prnt.sc/pdalnl**

I can upload successfully everything and I got what I need but there is another problem. On this media library I never see new uploaded files. From some point there is always same old files. But when I try to look my library media on wordpress admin when I select this menu item. **img: https://prnt.sc/pdan1j**

Than I get all my uploaded files and there I can see the new uploaded files. **img: https://prnt.sc/pdao1o** I tried upload sample.pdf so you can see that there is it. But it never shows on media library when I trying to achieve it from product page via custom field upload file button.

This is a metabox:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="file_download_url">URL:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="file_download_url" name="file_download_url[]" value="" class="file_download_url" style="width: 100%;"/></td>
<td><input id="upload_file_button_2" class="choose-image-btn button-secondary" type="button" value="Upload file" onclick="magnaplast_add_file(this,'."'".'#file_download_url'."'".');"/></td>
<td><input class="choose-image-btn button-secondary" type="button" value="Remove file" onclick="remove_form_part('."'".'#1'."'".');"/></td>
</tr>
```

This is a function:

```
function magnaplast_add_file(button, field) {
    formfield = jQuery(field).attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=file&TB_iframe=true');

    window.send_to_editor = function (html) {
        imgurl = jQuery(html).attr('href');
        jQuery(field).val(imgurl);

        tb_remove();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How was the Upload button added? Are you using a plugin? Also, could it be that you have some sort of caching enabled for the admin?

Comment: I checked all plugins. There is wp fastest cache and wp fastest cache premium. I tried to clear cache/deactivate plugins, but this didin't helped. Also I checked how upload buttons are addded, so it's added like a meta-box. With no plugin help. (it's not advanced custom fields or something like that.).

Comment: Also I found All In One WP Security plugin. But I don't think it have any cache functionality. I also tried to deactivate it.

Comment: How old are the files you do see? Can you post the code for the upload metabox? Also, are there any errors in your browser inspector?

Comment: I'm not sure about how old files are, but I updated questions with some code how upload file field works on this theme.

Comment: Oh, and there is no errors in console.

Comment: Javascript file last time edited was 2017. So I think this theme was developed around this time.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure but there's definitely something strange in that. If you can post the `tb_show` function as well that might help. Honestly if I were you I would just rebuild it from scratch, as it seems to be a sort of hacky job that you've posted and I'm guessing there's something weird going on with a database query somewhere. Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Ah, it's okay. Anyway thanks for help. I'm starting to think that I sould rebuild it too... By the way, I tried to find tb_show, but I can't find it in any theme file. I think it could be default wordpress function.